# php: how to get different values, store the in an array from the same form

Tags: php

i have a form, i want to get different data from this form and store theme in an array
like this:
entry1 (data1, data2, data3)
entry2 (data1, data2, data3)
entry3 (data2, data2, data3)
the question is this: when user press submit button the form be ready to get another data.
what is crossed my own mind to put it on the loop like this:

```
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        factor number :<input type="text" name="factor_number"><br><br>
        Customer name:<input type="text" name="customer_name"<br><br><br>
        branch: <input type="text" name="branch"><br><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        global $factor;
        global $factors;
        while ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $i++;
        
            $factor = array ($_REQUEST['factor_number'] ,
                             $_REQUEST['customer_name'] ,
                             $_REQUEST['branch']
                            );
                
                $factors = array ($i , $factor);
            $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == " ";
            
    
        }

    
         
    ?>
```

but it gets infinite
i know it might have a very plain answer so excuse me i'm new at the php :)

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck in a while loop. If you intend of only doing a set number of variables I would suggest a [loop](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) rather than a while. You could also add a counter and then break the while once the counter is reached.

Comment: thanks. the thing is sets of values are different. i need that every time user click on "submit" the form be ready to get another data. is there a function in php that can clear $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]???